# Can viewbag handle redirects while still maintaining its value?

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, view

i'm just wondering how to maintain it for some conditional if statements on the index page. on my index page i have a conditonal if statement set which will show the loginform if admin user is null, once submit is pressed this conditional if statement should no longer be loading the form instead the homepage and navbar should show.

```
     @if (ViewBag.Users == null)
{
         using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
         new { @class = 
                  "form-signin" }))
        {
             ///set text to be centered horizontolly
             <div class="text-center">

        <img class="mb-4" src="~/images/people.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserEmail, new { @type = "email", id = "inputEmail", Name = "Email Address", @class = "form-control", placeHolder = "Email Address", autocomplete = "off", required = "required" })
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @type = "password", id = "inputPassword", Name = "Password", @class = "form-control", placeHolder = "Password", autocomplete = "off", required = "required" })

        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>

           </div>
   }Html.EndForm();}
```

here is my view for the action

```
      [HttpPost][ActionName("ValidateUser")]
     public IActionResult ValidateUser(Users user)
         {
        ///check if modelstate is active once it is, retrieve the users 
      and add the new identity if it matches
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ///simulating a database call for users
            List<Users> admin = user.GetUsers();

           if(admin.FirstOrDefault().UserEmail == user.UserEmail && 
     admin.FirstOrDefault().Password == user.Password)
            {
                ViewBag.Users = user;

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        return View(user);
     }
```

The results i was currently expecting is that when viewbag.users != null then the form shouldn't show up at all

Summary: Once i press submit on the form it goes to the ValidateUser action to validate whether that person is admin or not. Then it saves the person details in Viewbag.Users. Hence viewbag.Users is not empty anymore therefore that if statement shouldn't be working anymore but it is still showing the login form

Answer:  viewbag doesn't presist between requests therefore use viewtemp or cookies or a query

Comment: Once i press submit on the form it goes to the ValidateUser action to validate whether that person is admin or not. Then it saves the person details in Viewbag.Users.  Hence viewbag.Users is not empty anymore therefore that if statement shouldn't be working anymore but it is still showing the login form

Comment: Are you thinking that `ViewBag` somehow persists between http requests? If so, the answer is No - it doesn't act like that. It is for a **single** http request only. _The `RedirectToAction` causes a separate http request._

Comment: No, your `ViewBag` values are lost during your redirects. You would need to use `TempData` to persist your values between redirects.

Comment: Does it not? then how would you persist an object

Comment: `TempData` would be one way (albeit not the one I would suggest). A querystring might be another. Or a cookie.

Comment: Perfect that i didn't know, it's been a couple days only for me. How would i use tempdata as in tempdata["Users"] = user

Comment: @mjwills i'm running it now but i think it should do the trick, tbh i should be using identity for log in but it's just to showcase on a portfolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your original question is:

No, your `ViewBag` values are lost during your redirects. You would need to use TempData to persist your values between redirects. A redirect is simply an empty response with a 301, 302, or 307 status code, and a Location response header. That Location header contains the the URL you'd like to redirect the client to.

BUT

You can use `TempData` to pass model data to a redirect request. You can pass simple types like string, int, Guid etc. If you want to pass a complex type object via TempData, you have can serialize your object to a string and pass that. I have made a simple test application that will suffice to your needs:

Your `Controller` would look like:

```
public ActionResult TestAction1(ClassA model)
{
    model.Id = "1";
    model.Name = "test";
    model.Marks.Grade = "A";
    model.Marks.Marks = 100;
    var complexObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    TempData["newuser"] = complexObj;
    return RedirectToAction("TestAction2");
}

public ActionResult TestAction2()
{
    if (TempData["newuser"] is string complexObj )
    {
        var getModel= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassA>(complexObj);
    }
    return View();
}
```

And your `Model` will look like:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        Marks = new StudentMarks();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public StudentMarks Marks { get; set; }
}

public class StudentMarks
{
    public int Marks { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

This is a very basic example on how you can use TempData to persist information between two controllers on a redirect action.

Answer (score 0):

ViewData and ViewBag are used for the same purpose to transfer data from controller to view.
By Using RedirectToAction("Index") You are creating new http-Request.
This ViewBag or ViewData will work for same http_Request i.e return View("Index").

As using RedirectToAction("Index") you are creating new http request you can use TempData.
( TempData is stored data just like live session for short time.) or a Cookie.